Why do the options not appear for my Snake game?
I am creating the snake game with a twist. I want questions to appear on top and their answers to appear randomly on the screen.
I am using turtle and creating classes while retrieving the question from a CSV file. I used the self.write method while creating a function in the answer class. I use randint to get x and y and also use hideturtle() and showturtle(), yet the options do not appear.
from snake import Snake
from turtle import Screen
from food import CorrectAnswer, WrongAnswer, SecondWrong
import pygame
import time
from score import ScoreBoard


snake = Snake()
screen = Screen()
food = CorrectAnswer()
food_2 = WrongAnswer()
food_3 = SecondWrong()
scoreboard = ScoreBoard()

screen.setup(width=600, height=600)
screen.title("My Snake Game")
#image = "snake.png"
#screen.addshape(image)
screen.bgcolor('light green')
screen.tracer(0)
pygame.mixer.init()

screen.listen()
screen.onkey(snake.up, "Up")
screen.onkey(snake.down, "Down")
screen.onkey(snake.left, "Left")
screen.onkey(snake.right,  "Right")

game_is_on = True

while game_is_on:
   screen.update()
   time.sleep(0.1)
   snake.move()

   if snake.head.distance(food) < 20:
       sound=pygame.mixer.Sound('Ding-sound-effect.mp3')
       pygame.mixer.Sound.play(sound)
       food.write_option()
       food_2.write_option()
       food_3.write_option()
       snake.extend()
       scoreboard.increase_score()

   if snake.head.distance(food_2) < 20:
       game_is_on=False

   if snake.head.distance(food_3) < 20:
       game_is_on=False

   if snake.head.xcor() > 290 or snake.head.xcor() < -290 or snake.head.ycor()>290 or snake.head.ycor() < -290:
       crash=pygame.mixer.Sound('losing-sound-effect.mp3')
       pygame.mixer.Sound.play(crash)
       time.sleep(2)
       scoreboard.reset()
       snake.reset()
   for segment in snake.segments[1:]:
        if snake.head.distance(segment) < 10:
            scoreboard.reset()

screen.mainloop()

food.py:
from turtle import Turtle
from score import current_id
import pandas
import random


data = pandas.read_csv("questions.csv")

class CorrectAnswer(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.hideturtle()

    def write_option(self, align="left", font=("Arial", 24, "normal")):
        self.penup()
        correct = data.loc[data['id'] == current_id, 'canswer'].values[0]
        self.goto(x=0, y=0)
        self.write(text=correct, align=align, font=font)
        self.pendown()
        self.showturtle()
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        self.clear()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(random.randint(-280, 280), random.randint(-280, 280))
        self.pendown()


class WrongAnswer(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.hideturtle()

    def write_option(self, align="left", font=("Arial", 24, "normal")):
        self.penup()
        correct = data.loc[data['id'] == current_id, 'wanswer'].values[0]
        self.goto(random.randint(-280, 280), random.randint(-280, 280))
        self.write(text=correct, align=align, font=font)
        self.pendown()
        self.showturtle()
        self.refresh()

    def refresh(self):
        self.clear()
        self.penup()
        self.goto(random.randint(-280, 280), random.randint(-280, 280))
        self.pendown()


class SecondWrong(Turtle):
    def __init__(self):
        super().__init__()
        self.speed("fastest")
        self.hideturtle()


In your classes CorrectAnswer and WrongAnswer, you call self.clear() in your self.refresh() method after writing the answer in self.write_option(). Thereby you remove the text instantly after drawing it.
From the docs:

turtle.clear()
Delete the turtle’s drawings from the screen. Do not move turtle. State and position of the turtle as well as drawings of other turtles are not affected.

For your next questions, please provide a minimal reproducible example.
Also, you might want to look into inheritance, instead of creating multiple almost identical classes (CorrectAnswer, WrongAnswer) that only differ in a single string: 'canswer' and 'wanswer'.
